# Adapt function to included Field Names C# 2012.net 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]Is their anyway of changing the below to included all fields names only and values one thing i noticted that when testing this it also brought other information about the entitiy back im only wanting the fields that have been entered or changed by the user??

```
 public static string ObjectToNotes(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj", "Value can not be null or Nothing!");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();

        for (int index = 0; index < pi.Length; index++)
        {
            sb.Append(pi[index].GetValue(obj, null));

            if (index < pi.Length - 1)
            {
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Right now this will save out the values for the entity only passed

As you can see from the image above the code is getting the values ok and fields but just not any drop downs related text

**Help 
Need more help with this how do i get the value of reference lookup values using the above method its only priting out the entity reference not the actual text value can this be done**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by entered by the user you mean not having a string representation that is null or empty then try the following:

```
var properties = t.GetProperties();
var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(obj, null)).Where(v => v != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ToString());
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values);
```

In order to determine whcih fields have changed, you will need to pass two objects. One representing the entity in its pre-changed state and the other in its post-changed state and compare the properties:

```
var properties = t.GetProperties();
var before = properties.Select(p => new { property = p, value = p.GetValue(prechange, null) }).Where(v => v.value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.value.ToString()).ToDictionary(p => p.property.Name, p => p.value);
var after = properties.Select(p => new { property = p, value = p.GetValue(postchange, null) }).Where(v => v.value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.value.ToString()).ToDictionary(p => p.property.Name, p => p.value);
// You can then compare the keys / values of before and after dictionaries here
```

Comment: okkelly Yes some strings can be empty its basically to capture all the fields on the form so it can be saved as a audit record backup so they no what has changed

Comment: is their anyway to get the lookup values references to be intact ie the reference has already been made but its just returning the codes not description

Comment: @DavidB The above code will return the result of calling `ToString` on the given property. You can either override the ToString method in all appropriate types to make them output something more meaningful, create a new interface that has an appropriate `ToFrindlyString` method on it and use that if the property is of that type, or attempt to recursively navigate through the properties of the property until one is of the appropriate type. However, I feel that such a discussion probably warrants another question. Hope this helps